# Как отфильтровать pandas.DataFrame по столбцу, состоящему из списков в зависимости от наличия в списке тех или иных элементов?

Tags: python, pandas, сортировка, list, dataframe

Имеется pandas.DataFrame, в котором записана информация о школьных уроках и курсах. Среди неё имеется **список** классов, которые этот курс могут посещать (например, если это 9-11 класс, то будет записано [9, 10, 11] ***в типе int***). Итак, предположим нужно получить список курсов, которые может посещать 8 класс. В Pandas это обычно делается с помощью булевского индексирования:

```
df = df[df['нужный_параметр'] == нужный_объект]
```

В результате часть `df['нужный_параметр'] == нужный_объект` возвращает список из значений `True` и `False`, где напротив каждого индекса указано, соответствует ли строка под этим индексом в DataFrame заданному параметру. Далее `df[[bool-список]]` возвращает только те значения, по индексу которых в bool-списке указано `True`.

Но как я писал выше, классы для посещения курсов записаны в списке из `int`, а не в `str` или `int`. Итак, пробуем:

```
df = df[8 in df['grades']]
```

В результате Python пожалуется с помощью `KeyError` на то, что `df[]` ожидал список из значений типа `bool`, что справедливо, ведь часть `8 in df['grades']` возвращает лишь один `bool`. Почему это происходит? Pandas образует bool-список только с мат. операторами и операторами сравнения строк? Плюс к тому же: в `df['grades']` попросту нет значения `8`; в этом столбце есть только **списки**, в которых имеется этот элемент (`[8, ...]`). Так почему же `8 in df['grades']` тогда возвращает `True`? Выходит, что `df['grades']` возвращает список, в котором смешано содержимое всех списков столбца (и как в таком случае фильтровать DataFrame)?

Попробуем вручную создать этот самый bool-список и с его помощью отфильтровать DataFrame:

```
tf = []
for i in range(len(database['grades'])):
    if 8 in database['grades'][i]:
        tf.append(True)
    else:
        tf.append(False)
database = database[tf]
```

Это работает, но очевидно, что этот код громоздкий и возможно ресурсоёмкий. Как же привести всю эту обработку к удобному виду `df = df[df['нужный_параметр'] == нужный_объект]`? Если нет, как это привести к максимально удобному виду? Можно ли это сделать с помощью конструктора (`tf = [i for i in ...]`)? Как завести этот самый список в отдельном столбце в DataFrame и как этот столбец быстро заполнить (я помню, что делал это, но сейчас забыл как)?

*P. S. Понимаю, что возможно усложнил вопрос, но сделал его полным для получения полного ответа. Заранее благодарю, за то что прочитали всё и уделили вопросу внимание!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть есть Dataframe:

```
            A
0    [3, 4, 5]
1  [9, 10, 11]
```

тогда:

```
num = 9
df["A"].apply(lambda x: num in x)
```

результат:

```
0    False
1     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы можно только через `lambda` сделать, встроенной функции для этого не нашёл:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'grades': [[9, 10, 11],[8, 10, 11],[8, 9]], 'something': [1,2,3]})
df[df.grades.apply(lambda x: 8 in x)]
```

Результат:

```
    grades      something
1   [8, 10, 11] 2
2   [8, 9]      3
```

Ответ подсмотрен [на англоязычной части Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41518959/8324991)